# IF parameter statement merged with time format

Tags: if-statement, reporting-services, parameters, sum, floor

I am trying to do an IF statement based on the parameter (Average or Total). However I am struggling with how to put the two together.

```
=Floor(Sum(Fields!Avg_ACD_Time.Value)/ 3600) &":"& Format(DateAdd("s",Sum(Fields!Avg_ACD_Time.Value), "00:00"), "mm:ss")

=IIF(Parameters!ReportType.Value="Average", Sum(Fields!Avg_ACD_Time.Value)/CountRows(), Sum(Fields!Avg_ACD_Time.Value))
```

Many thanks

Comment: In wich case you have to put the first expression, maybe when Parameter.Value is not `"Average"`?

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work:

```
=IIF(Parameters!ReportType.Value="Average", 
Floor((Sum(Fields!Avg_ACD_Time.Value)/CountRows()) / 3600) & ":" & Format(DateAdd("s", Sum(Fields!Avg_ACD_Time.Value)/CountRows(), "00:00"), "mm:ss"), 
Floor(Sum(Fields!Avg_ACD_Time.Value)/ 3600) &":"& Format(DateAdd("s",Sum(Fields!Avg_ACD_Time.Value), "00:00"), "mm:ss"))
```

You just need to replace the `Sum(Fields!Avg_ACD_Time.Value)` with `Sum(Fields!Avg_ACD_Time.Value)/CountRows()` for the average.

Comment: Hi, The above works perfectly however how do I now add in IF(Sum(Fields!Avg_ACD_Time.Value) =0,0 then change to IF(Sum(Fields!Avg_ACD_Time.Value) =0,1    thank you